# Lucene.NET in medium trust

Tags: .net, asp.net, lucene, lucene.net, medium-trust

How do I make [Lucene.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucene#Lucene.NET) 2.3.2 run in a medium trust environment? [GoDaddy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_Daddy) doesn't like it the way it is.

Answer (score 1):

It should work. Lucene.NET [was made compatible](http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENENET-169) with a medium trust environment in commits [788091](http://osdir.com/ml/lucene-net-commits.incubator.apache.org/2009-06/msg00001.html) and [788092](http://osdir.com/ml/lucene-net-commits.incubator.apache.org/2009-06/msg00002.html), which went into the 2.3.2 release. You can verify this by looking at the history of the [2.3.2 tag](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/lucene.net/tags/Lucene.Net_2_3_2/) with your favorite [Subversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion) client.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://sailens.com/details.aspx?item=2&q=love

Doesn't look like it's been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I just recently struggled with this, and wanted to update this with a solution I got to work. I pulled down the latest code and built it myself so I could make changes if needed.  In the SupportClass.cs file, starting at line 481 there is some code that verifies a file buffer has been flushed using unmanaged code.

```
        if (OS.IsWindows)
        {
            if (!FlushFileBuffers(fileStream.Handle))
                throw new System.IO.IOException();
        }
        else if (OS.IsUnix)
        {
            if (fsync(fileStream.Handle) != IntPtr.Zero)
            throw new System.IO.IOException();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

I commented out these lines and rebuilt the library and was able to run in medium trust. I ran locally in medium trust, as well as putting together a simple test app deployed to GoDaddy.  I'm not sure what the implications are of removing these lines. They appear to be duplicating the behavior of the `fileStream.Flush()` call that precedes this block, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I too have the same problem, have you seen any problems after `commenting` the code out?

Answer (score 0):

I have just posted this question within the lucene users group and it has been recommended that you use the following:-

```
public static void Sync(System.IO.FileStream fileStream)
{
  if (fileStream == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("fileStream");

  //Will only compile with .net 4.0
  fileStream.Flush(true);
}
```

> **Quote** from user group email:-
>
> However, at the time, Lucene.NET was
>   built on .NET 2.0 (IIRC) and didn't
>   have access to the overload of the
>   Flush method which was used to
>   guarantee everything was flushed to
>   disk:
>
> http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/3k9XU33O4yJyW15fWfMd#MhNDlmKgnUj5fOj
>
> Since you are now working in .NET 4.0,
>   you should be able to replace the
>   above code in SupportClass.cs