# Lucene .NET 2.3.2 Security Exception - Medium trust Issues

Tags: c#, .net, full-text-search, lucene, lucene.net

I'm only partially able to get Lucene .NET to work on GoDaddy.  It throws a security exception on this line:

Hits hits = searcher.Search(query, filter);

Here are the details of this exception:

```
Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file.

Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

    [SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.]
   WeakHashTable.set_Item(Object key, Object value) in SupportClass.cs:1231
   Lucene.Net.Search.CachingWrapperFilter.Bits(IndexReader reader) in CachingWrapperFilter.cs:69
   Lucene.Net.Search.IndexSearcher.Search(Weight weight, Filter filter, HitCollector results) in IndexSearcher.cs:175
   Lucene.Net.Search.IndexSearcher.Search(Weight weight, Filter filter, Int32 nDocs) in IndexSearcher.cs:156
   Lucene.Net.Search.Hits.GetMoreDocs(Int32 min) in Hits.cs:104
   Lucene.Net.Search.Hits..ctor(Searcher s, Query q, Filter f) in Hits.cs:67
   Lucene.Net.Search.Searcher.Search(Query query, Filter filter) in Searcher.cs:57
   details.RetrieveDocument() in d:\hosting\5304481\html\details.aspx.cs:42
   details.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\hosting\5304481\html\details.aspx.cs:28
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +50
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +6785
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +242
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() +80
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context) +21
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +49
   ASP.details_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in App_Web_pux0zsik.0.cs:0
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +181
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75
```

Before I give up on GoDaddy and move to DiscountASP, I wanted to check if anyone would know how I can tweak the code to operate fully in a Medium Trust environment.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have answered a different question on getting Lucene.Net to work in medium trust. This is on newer versions of the library.

[Lucene.NET in medium trust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837161/lucene-net-in-medium-trust/5824481#5824481)

Comment: Also see my answer on the post that @NerdFury is pointing to.